# CORS jQuery petición a API con AJAX

Tags: jquery, xampp, cors

intento hacer una petición a una API con AJAX. Estoy utilizando XAMPP y me da el siguiente error

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

Por lo que estuve leyendo debo habilitar CORS, ¿puedo hacer esto en mi archivo .js o debo hacer la petición en PHP?

Answer (score 1):

Tu js realiza la petición al API, y es el API la que debe tener configurado CORS, que es el intercambio de orígenes cruzados. Podemos tener configurado CORS para que sólo puedan consultar el API ciertas aplicaciones, o todas, o por ejemplo, solo acepte peticiones GET. Todo esto hay que configurarlo en el API, en tu caso, en PHP.

Puedes crear una función o método, depende de la metodología de programación que uses, como la que te indico abajo, en la que le pasas los datos en un array, y mediante la función json_encode los envía en formato json.

Como puedes ver, justo antes, se configuran las cabeceras, tu configuración dependerá de las solicitudes que realices, y de cómo quieres configurar tu API.

```
function envio_json($datos){
   header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
   header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
   header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS');
   header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With");
   header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
   header('P3P: CP="IDC DSP COR CURa ADMa OUR IND PHY ONL COM STA"');
   echo json_encode($datos);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo solucioné una vez cuando me sucedió lo mismo, agregando esta linea de código si estas en PHP al inicio de tu script

```
<?php header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); ?>+
```

Te comparto un enlace que puede servir para mas dudas
https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/

Te recomiendo tambien usar alguna herramienta como cloud9, ya que en ocasiones con XAMPP o WAMP se presentan distintos problemas que no suceden en un servidor cuando llevas tu desarrollo a producción, con cloud9 tienes una maquina linux para hacer tus proyectos y se sincroniza con git

Espero te sirva