# Access to XMLHttpRequest

Tags: jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest

Hola compañeros programadores, actualmente trabajo en una pagina web y deseaba añadirle una petición a un archivo por medio de Jquery AJAX (Es mi primera utilizando AJAX), pero me marca los siguientes errores al hacer click a la link de etiqueta #loadCatalogue

> 1.Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'file:///C:/Users/Juan%20Esteban/OneDrive%20-%20Games/Escritorio/MiCarpeta/Diyey45%20Studio/Proyectos/En%20proceso/zamaju/MorePages/catalogue.html' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.

> 2.Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'file:///C:/Users/Juan%20Esteban/OneDrive%20-%20Games/Escritorio/MiCarpeta/Diyey45%20Studio/Proyectos/En%20proceso/zamaju/MorePages/catalogue.html' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.

Mi codigo Html

```
<div class="menuFixed">
  <main>
    <div><a href="#"><img src="#" alt="#"></a></div>
    <div><a id="loadCatalogue">Catalogo</a></div>
  </main>
</div>


<div class="container" id="container">

</div>
```

Mi codigo JS

```
$('#loadCatalogue').click(function(){
      var esperar = 2000;
      $.ajax({
        url:"MorePages/catalogue.html",
        beforeSend : function () {
          $('#container').text('Cargando...');
        },
        succes: function(data){
          setTimeout(function() {
            $('#container').html(data);
          },esperar
        );
        }
      });
    });
```

Comment: Duplicada de muchas otras preguntas. Entre ellas [CORS jQuery petición a API con AJAX](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/169933/cors-jquery-petici%c3%b3n-a-api-con-ajax)

Comment: No estoy llamando un archivo PHP estoy es llamando un archivo JSON

Comment: CORS no tiene que ver con que recurso específico estás pidiendo (html, json, php), si con la fuente y el origen.